# use signton and factory design pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, factory

```
file AuthLogin.js            

            import axios from "axios";
            const LISTS = {
              USER: "Users",
              STAFF: "DoStaff",
              DOCTOR: "ctor",
              CLINIC: "Clinic",
              EPHARMACY_ADMIN: "EpharmacyAdmin",
            };
            
            // const baseURL = "https://user.api.edoctor.io";
            const baseURL = process.env.USER_API;
            
            const AuthLogin = () => {
              const AuthAPI = (() => {
                var instance;
            
                const http = axios.create({
                  baseURL: baseURL,
                  headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  },
                });
            
                const createInstance = () => {
                  return {
                    signOut: (url) => signOut(url),
                    signIn: (url, payload) => signIn(url, payload),
                    signInFB: (url, payload) => signInFB(url, payload),
                    signInSmsVerify: (url, payload) => signInSmsVerify(url, payload),
                    signInSmsRequest: (url, payload) => signInSmsRequest(url, payload),
                    signInGoogle: (url, platform, idToken) =>
                      signInGoogle(url, platform, idToken),
                  };
                };
            
                const signInSmsRequest = async (url, payload) => {
                  await http.post(url, payload);
                };
            
                const signInSmsVerify = async (url, payload) => {
                  const response = await http.post(url, payload);
                  return response?.data;
                };
            
                const signIn = async (url, payload) => {
                  const response = await http.post(url, payload);
                  return response?.data;
                };
            
                const signInFB = async (url, accessToken) => {
                  const response = await http.post(url, { accessToken });
                  return response?.data;
                };
            
                const signInGoogle = async (url, platform, idToken) => {
                  const response = await http.post(url, { platform, idToken });
                  return response?.data;
                };
            
                const signOut = async (url) => {
                  return "signOut";
                  // return await http.post("auth/sign_out", {});
                };
            
                return {
                  getInstance: () => {
                    if (!instance) instance = createInstance();
                    return instance;
                  },
                };
              })();
            
              const authFactory = (() => {
                const createAuth = function (type) {
                  return getLists(type);
                };
                return { createAuth };
              })();
            
              const getLists = (type) => {
                var lists = {
                  Doctor: () => {
                    return {
                      signInSmsRequest: (url, payload) =>
                        authAPI.signInSmsRequest(url, payload),
                      signInSmsVerify: (url, payload) =>
                        authAPI.signInSmsVerify(url, payload),
                    };
                  },
                  EpharmacyAdmin: () => {
                    return {
                      signOut: (url) => authAPI.signOut(url),
                      signIn: (url, payload) => authAPI.signIn(url, payload),
                    };
                  },
                };
                return lists[type]();
              };
            
              var authAPI = AuthAPI.getInstance();
            
              return {
                LISTS,
                useAPI: () => authAPI,
                useAuth: (key) => authFactory.createAuth(key),
              };
            };
            export default AuthLogin;
       
file App.js
          const { useAPI, LISTS, useAuth } = AuthLogin();
          useEffect(() => {
            (async () => {
            await useAuth(LISTS.EPHARMACY_ADMIN).signOut();
            })();
          }, []);
```

Singletons are useful in situations where system-wide actions need to be coordinated from a single central place. An example is a database connection pool. The pool manages the creation, destruction, and lifetime of all database connections for the entire application ensuring that no connections are 'lost'.

An Abstract Factory creates objects that are related by a common theme. In object-oriented programming a Factory is an object that creates other objects. An Abstract Factory has abstracted out a theme which is shared by the newly created objects.

I am trying to understand a very commonly used design pattern Factory and signton and I have put together the best possible but my code overlaps a lot and I don't have a workaround yet and don't know anyway. more optimal? Hope you help?

Answer (score 0):

OOP principles can be used in React but it's not always exactly the same due to the way that React handles `state` and re-rendering.

When you have a "singleton" type of situation in React, usually what you want to do is use a [`Context.Provider`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to make the same instance available to your whole app. An example of this would be if the user is logged in and we want to make their user details and auth token available so that we can access them in other components which are deeper in the tree.

Your `AuthLogin` here doesn't appear to have any instance variables since `baseURL` is a constant.  It could just as well be `static` or you could have independent functions.  Every instance is essentially the same.  That is in contrast to something like a "Session" where you could create infinitely many unique sessions, but we want to be accessing the same distinct one always.  That's where a singleton and a `Context` makes sense.

As far as the repetitive sign-ins, you can have one behind-the-scenes utility function and your other functions can just map arguments to it.  Your `signIn` already does this:

```
const signIn = async (url, payload) => {
  const response = await http.post(url, payload);
  return response?.data;
};
```

`signInSmsVerify` is an identical function and does not need to exist.  You can keep this as a variable if you want, but just assign it to the existing function.

```
const signInSmsVerify = signIn
```

`signInGoogle` and `signInFB` map their unique function arguments to the `payload` object.  You can create functions which take those arguments and then use them to call the `signIn` function.

```
const signInGoogle = (url, platform, idToken) => signIn(url, { platform, idToken })
```

(An alternative structure would be to have functions which create unique payloads, such as `googlePayload = (platform, idToken) => ({ platform, idToken })` Rather than having a function `signInGoogle`, you would sign in using Google by calling `signIn(url, googlePayload(platform, idToken))`. I actually prefer this, but I don't want to veer too far from where you are going)

```
const createInstance = () => {
  return {
    signOut: (url) => signOut(url),
    signIn: (url, payload) => signIn(url, payload),
    signInFB: (url, payload) => signInFB(url, payload),
    signInSmsVerify: (url, payload) => signInSmsVerify(url, payload),
    signInSmsRequest: (url, payload) => signInSmsRequest(url, payload),
    signInGoogle: (url, platform, idToken) =>
      signInGoogle(url, platform, idToken),
  };
};
```

The mapping of arguments here is completely unnecessary as these are already arrow functions.  You can return the `const` functions directly:

```
const createInstance = () => {
  return {
    signOut,
    signIn,
    signInFB,
    signInSmsVerify,
    signInSmsRequest,
    signInGoogle
  };
};
```

Or you can avoid creating those functions at all and use this return object as a way to map arguments to the core `signIn` function.

```
const createAuthHelper = (http) => {
  const signIn = async (url, payload) => {
    const response = await http.post(url, payload);
    return response?.data;
  };

  return ({
    signIn,
    signInSmsVerify: signIn,
    signInSmsRequest: http.post, // not sure why this is needed
    signInFB: (url, accessToken) => signIn(url, { accessToken }),
    signInGoogle: (url, platform, idToken) => signIn(url, { platform, idToken }),
  })
}
```

Here I have passed the `http` object as an argument to make this flexible and reusable.  But you can use this to create one global constant.

```
const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.USER_API,
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

const myAuthHelper = createAuthHelper(http);
```